# "fontfamily" versus "font-family" - the latter is preferred?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I just asked a question on SO that was referencing the CSS "font-family" rule.

It was my understanding that tags with multiple words should be separated by a dash `-`.

The tag that came up when I typed `font-family` was [fontfamily](/questions/tagged/fontfamily).

Two questions:

1. Would [font-family](/questions/tagged/font-family) be the preferred way to write this?
2. If so, is there a way to rename the tag so that all the posts using it use the new format?

Of course, a synonym could be set up so that [font-family](/questions/tagged/font-family) is a synonym for [fontfamily](/questions/tagged/fontfamily), but assuming the latter is incorrect, that would just be putting a minor fix on the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like a better question to ask is:

> Why is there a [fontfamily](/questions/tagged/fontfamily) tag at all?

Do we need a tag for every CSS attribute? Why doesn't [css](/questions/tagged/css) cover it? I see a few misguided tagging attempts in the question list for [fonttamily](/questions/tagged/fonttamily):

[fontfamily](/questions/tagged/fontfamily), [fontsize](/questions/tagged/fontsize), [li](/questions/tagged/li), [dropdownlist](/questions/tagged/dropdownlist), [font-face](/questions/tagged/font-face), [pre](/questions/tagged/pre), [dropdown-menu](/questions/tagged/dropdown-menu)

And these are just the ones that intersect with [fontfamily](/questions/tagged/fontfamily): there seems to be a tag for nearly every single CSS selector, HTML element, and UI control. They should all just go away: tagging is meant to categorize questions into useful segments so people can follow them, not to make sure keywords show up on the question. That's what the question body is for.

So instead of using [fontfamily](/questions/tagged/fontfamily) or [font-family](/questions/tagged/font-family) because you happen to use the attribute in your question, just use [css](/questions/tagged/css) and add any other tag you think a reasonable person interested in answering your question would follow: maybe [fonts](/questions/tagged/fonts) if it's specifically a font problem.

Comment: My favorite is the [p](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p) tag, used for questions remotely related to the html `<p>` tag. Totally agree with you here, often people just break the question title up into tags. "How do I style a list with CSS?" gets tagged [how] [style] [list] [with] [css]

Comment: Perhaps you could add: [ol], [ul], [center], [leftalign], [div], etc. to the list?  However, for certain things, like [abbr], they might be obscure enough to merit their own tag?  perhaps.  Just my $0.02

Comment: You realize @Wesley, that I and about five others just ran over to see if [how] is *really* a tag....  Nope.  I believe it was blacklisted.

Comment: Even some html entities apparently have their own tag. Note to self: This year, earn gold badge in the [\[nbsp\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nbsp) tag. Next year: Step up my game to earn the [\[non-breaking-spaces\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-breaking-spaces) Gold Badge.

Comment: So you suggest [tag:fontfamily] be BURNINATED?